# Photoslide javascript is working in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have got three pages/divs sliding through (on one index page) using javascript/jquery, and a couple of pages/divs are set on timer. Please see my code and function on http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/35/

Everything is working perfectly in Firefox, but the slide and the timer are not working in IE.

How can I fix this javascript/IE problem please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you posted is the actual code you're using, comment out or remove the console.log statement. IE chokes on them if the debugger isn't open.

Comment: Hi @j08691, thanks for your fast response. Sorry what is the console.log statement please? (I'm still learning) Would you be able to give me an example in my code? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, in the jsFiddle you posted you have the line `console.log($this.attr('href'));`. This is usually used for debugging jQuery and JavaScript and just sends output to the browser's debug console. When you put code into production it's best to remove, or at least comment the console.log lines out. IE has the added benefit of choking on these lines if the code is run and the debugger is closed (as it normally would be). Other browsers just ignore it and continue to work.